# How to stop a Bash script with the space bar?

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on a Rubik’s Cube stopwatch written in Bash and I would like to stop it by hitting the space bar since <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not feasible when you have to terminate it as fast as you can.

So is there a way to stop the program just with the space bar?

I looked up at the command `kill` by I couldn’t figure out.

The stopwatch part of the code is below:

```
TMP0=$(date +%s%N)
while true; do
    TMP1=$(date +%s%N)
    DTMP=$(($TMP1-$TMP0))
    printf "\r$(($DTMP/1000000000)).${DTMP:(-9):2}"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

It's your terminal who sends SIGINT to the foreground process group when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. You can configure it to do this upon any character, but you want to restore the old settings when the script exits.

```
#!/bin/bash

settings="$(stty -g)"
trap 'stty "$settings"' EXIT
stty intr ' '

TMP0=$(date +%s%N)
while true; do
    TMP1=$(date +%s%N)
    DTMP=$(($TMP1-$TMP0))
    printf '\r%s' "$(($DTMP/1000000000)).${DTMP:(-9):2}"
done
```

`settings="$(stty -g)"` saves the old settings; `stty intr ' '` makes the terminal react to <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>; `trap 'stty "$settings"' EXIT` is responsible for restoring the old settings when the script exits.

Notes:

- <strike>In the code of the trap, `stty $settings` is better than `stty "$settings"`. It's an exception from the "[always quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618)" rule. Quoting prevents word splitting and filename generation (globbing), but some implementations of `stty` may require word splitting, for them the variable mustn't be quoted. To avoid harmful side effects from filename generation, the [specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html) requires `stty -g` to generate a string that doesn't trigger this feature.</strike>

  Edit: [that was a defect in the POSIX specification](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1532). The above code has been fixed.
- In case something goes wrong and you find yourself in an interactive shell where <kbd>Space</kbd> still generates SIGINT, you need to invoke `stty intr ^C` by hand. There are spaces in the command, but keep in mind you can still type a literal space character by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>.
- I used `printf '\r%s' …` because I think a static format and dynamic data fit the "philosophy" of `printf` better than dynamic format you used.

"<kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>" means when <kbd>Space</kbd> becomes special, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> stops being special. You may call it a flaw because [users will expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to remain special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Making both special at the same time is not trivial though, I think it cannot be done by configuring the terminal.

This alternative version stops upon almost any key, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> works as usual:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r -t 0.001; do :; done    # dump the buffer
TMP0=$(date +%s%N)
until read -r -n 1 -t 0.001; do
    TMP1=$(date +%s%N)
    DTMP=$(($TMP1-$TMP0))
    printf '\r%s' "$(($DTMP/1000000000)).${DTMP:(-9):2}"
done
echo
```

To make it react on <kbd>Space</kbd> only you need to check what has been read:

```
…
until read -r -n 1 -t 0.001 && [ "$REPLY" = ' ' ]; do
…
```

Note the mechanism of <kbd>Space</kbd> stopping the script is now very different than how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> works.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the stopwatch, after all, you just want to know the time it took in the end anyway, you can use:

```
time read -r -n 1
```

it'll give you an output like:

```
time read -r -n 1

real    1m30.909s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

and stop with pretty much any keystroke (similar to how Kamil uses `read`)

or if you just want the time part:

```
{ time read -r -n 1; } 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

courtesy of [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257787/2671179)